# Lock code section to one entrance at a time

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, locking

I am trying to restrict access to an singletone object so only one thread
use it at time, Furthermore, I want to prevent from the same thread accessing twice 
to the restricted code.

I tried the Lock method and i found out that its dosn't lock the thread that locked her, but only other threads..

as below:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Singleton instance    = new Singleton();

    static Singleton()
    {
    }

    private Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    { 
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }
}

public class SomeWorker
{
    private readonly Timer _doWorkTimer = new Timer(20);

    public SomeWorker()
    {
        InitiateTimer();
    }

    private void InitiateTimer()
    { 
        _doWorkTimer .Elapsed += DoWorkElapse;
        _doWorkTimer .Enabled = true;
    }

    private void DoWorkElapse(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    { 
        DoSomeWork();
    }

    private void DoSomeWork()
    {
        // I know that lock on string is wrong!
        // Its just for the example only I
        // Its just to make sure all the program is use the same lock..
        lock ("ConnectionLock")
        { 
             Console.WriteLine("Lock");

             var inst = Singletone.Instance;

             // Do Some Work on "inst" ...

             Console.WriteLine("Unlock");
        }
    }
}
```

The result in the console for example is:

.
.
.

Lock

Unlock

**Lock**

**Lock**

Unlock

.
.
.

As we can see, 2 Lock comments shows one after another

So its mean that the "DoSomeWork()" accessed twice by the timer thread.

Anyone have any idea how to make this lock work?

Other Sync methods maby?

thanx.

Comment: when you say you found out that it doesn't lock the thread that locked her, but only the other threads - how did you find that out?

Comment: Simpley put Console.WriteLine("Lock" + threadName) after the { of the lock and Console.WriteLine("Unlock" + threadName) before the },
The result in the console was "LockTrd, LockTrd, UnlockTrd..."
2 Locks together..

Answer (score 4):

You aren't doing your locking properly (and to top it off you are taking a lock on a string which is a big no-no).  To save time, please read [this](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) article from Jon Skeet and implement one of the patterns to save yourself a headache.

Comment: @daniel: I'm a bit puzzled about what you are trying to accomplish.  Can you please explain exactly what you are trying to do more clearly?  Please edit your original post so we can try and serve you better.

Comment: @daniel:  Is this a complete code sample of your code?  I can't duplicate your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have

```
public static Singletone Instance()
{
    if (_instance == null)
    {
        lock (_instance)
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new Singletone ();
            }
        }
    }
    return _instance;;
}
```

Think about it. `if (_instance == null)` you do `lock (_instance)`. So you lock using `null`. That's not good at all.

In MSDN [lock Statement (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) the given example of how to use `lock` is:

```
class Account
{
    decimal balance;
    private Object thisLock = new Object();

    public void Withdraw(decimal amount)
    {
        lock (thisLock)
        {
            if (amount > balance)
            {
                throw new Exception("Insufficient funds");
            }
            balance -= amount;
        }
    }
}
```

I guess you should follow it and have a separate object to use it as a lock.

---

And secondly, [thread syncronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) primitives are used to separate access to shared resources for different threads. If you need to separate access from one thread, you simply need to use flags. Something like this:

```
bool isBusy = false;
public static void Foo()
{
    if (!isBusy)
    {
        isBusy = true;
        try
        {            
            //do the job
        }
        finally
        {
            isBusy = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here you should understand that you simply skip the "locked-by-flag" code. On the contrary if you want to make the thread wait for itself, especially in a multithreading application, I guess it looks like it should be redesigned.

Comment: 1) The flag isn't thread safe because one thread can pass the 
if(!isBusy) then stop, And another thread can pass the same if because the first one didn't change the flag yet.
2) In case the "Source" i am trying to protect from access is busy i don't want to give up the action like the if() doing, i want it to wait, And replacing th if(!isBusy) with while(isBusy) doing the job but its bad to performance..

Comment: @daniel, I never said, that flags are thread safe. You wanted to block one thread from itself, this is what flags can be used for. None of the thread syncronization primitives can help in doing this straightforwardly....

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to implement a singleton in .NET is:

```
public class Singleton : IDisposable
{
    private readonly static Singleton _instance = new Singleton();
    private readonly static object lockObject = new object();

    static Singleton()
    {
    }

    private Singleton()
    {
        InitiateConnection();
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get { return _instance; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method that accesses the DB.
    /// </summary>
    public void DoWork()
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            //Do Db work here. Only one thread can execute these commands at a time.                
        }
    }        

    ~Singleton()
    {
        //Close the connection to DB.

        //You don't want to make your singleton class implement IDisposable because
        //you don't want to allow a call to Singleton.Instance.Dispose().
    }
}
```

Read the excellent article on [Singleton Pattern implementations in .NET](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) that Bryan suggested in his answer. The above implementation is based on the fourth version described in the article. The CLR guarantees that the construction of the static field will thread-safe hence you do not need locking there. However you will need locking if your object has state (fields) that can be changed.

Note that there is a `private readonly object` used for ensuring mutual exclusion on the `DoWork` method. This way a single thread can call `DoWork` at a time. Also note that there is no way that the same thread can call this method twice at the same time since a thread executes instructions sequentially. The only way this method could be called twice from a single thread is if inside `DoWork` you call another method that eventually calls `DoWork`. I can't see the point of doing this and if you do then take care to avoid stack overflows. You could follow the suggestion of Konstantin and use a flag but IMHO you should redesign `DoWork` to do just one thing and avoid scenarios like these.

Comment: The second question was that not only i want to have one istance and that y i need the singelton, I need to restrict the access to it to one at time, the singleton is DB access, and i want to manege sum sort of queue to use it, So all the threads use this DB access use it one after one, And even if the same thread try to access the DB twice from different methods in the same time one of the methods will be blocked..

Hope i explained myself well..